# Difference between support of a section and nonvanishing locus of a section.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to wrap my head around the fact that if I take a global section $ f \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) $. Then the support $ Supp (s) = \{ p \in X : s_p \neq 0 \} $ is closed, but the locus $ X_s = \{ p \in X : s_p \notin \mathfrak{m}_p\mathcal{O}_p \} $ is open.

Any help in understanding this difference would be appreciated. Also to help with this
I tried to calculate $ Supp(s) $ and $ X_s $, for $ X = Spec (k[x,y]) $ and $ s = y-x^2 $. But had
no idea on how to calculate the germ at a point $ p \in X $. Would also appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Did you make a typo in the definition of $X_s$? I would expect that to have either $\notin$ in place of $\in$ or for "open" to be "closed".

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching that. I've edited the question.

Comment: I have corrected your definition of $X_s$ (which did not make sense) and replaced your $s(p)$ by the correct $s_p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest example showing the  difference between $supp(s)$ and $X_s$.
Let $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal F=\mathcal C$, the sheaf of real valued continuous functions on $\mathbb R$.
Consider the identity function $s\in \mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ defined by $s(t)=t$ for  $t\in \mathbb R$.
Then $X_s=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, which is open, and   $supp(s)=\mathbb R$, which is closed.

**Remark**
Does this example seem childish? Of course it is! I think the duty of a teacher is to make as large a chunk of mathematics as possible seem childish, especially when introducing new concepts.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $s_p=0$ then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $s_{|U}=0$. Similarly if $s_p$ is invertible then $s_{|U}$ is invertible for some neighborhood $U$ of $p$.